# How to check Procedure Ownership?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On Snowflake that is easy to check other objects ownership by running (e.g.): "SHOW TABLES" - column OWNER will be there.

If, however, we try "SHOW PROCEDURES", ownership is not shown.

Do we have a workaround for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/procedures.html):

> This Information Schema view displays a row for each stored procedure defined in the specified (or current) database.
>
> **PROCEDURE_OWNER** Name of the role that owns the stored procedure

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES
WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME ILIKE '<procedure_name_here>';
```